# Creating custom file extension with windows registry

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-registry, file-extension

Ok, so I have been reading and googling this for a while now and I can't understand what is going wrong.  I am trying to create a .int file extension in my registry so that I can add the ShellNew key to it and thus it should allow me to do the simple right click > new > file method of file creation.  So I went to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and I created a key called .int.
I then created a key called intfile with a default icon and set its (Default) string to "Localization File".  Then in my .int key I set the (Default) intfile and created Content Type which i set to plain/text.  Then I created a new key called ShellNew and in that key I set FileName to the path in WINDOWS/ShellNew where my default .int file was.  However, when I right click and go to new it does not show New Localization File.  Am I missing a registry entry somewhere?  Any help will be greatly appreciated, I can't figure out why this isn't working as I have added ShellNew to many keys before and had it always worked flawlessly.  This is my first time creating a completely new file extension but I have read other file extensions that exist and can't see why it isn't working.  Ty again in advance.

Edit:  Clarification of what I have set up exactly.

```
intfile:
     (Default) REG_SZ "Localization File"
intfile>shell>open>command:
     (Default) REG_SZ "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
.int: 
     (Default) REG_SZ "intfile"
     ContentType REG_SZ "plain/text"
     Percieved Type REG_SZ "text"
.int>ShellNew:
     (Default) REG_SZ "null"
     FileName REG_SZ "C:\WINDOWS\ShellNew\New Int.int"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's cause you didn't register your file type correctly. Well, technically, you didn't register your "application" correct.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144148(v=vs.85).aspx#fa_register_type\

You registered .int correctly. `.int` says to call `intfile`. **intfile** however is where you put in the application that handles the file!  So Shellex goes looking into `intfile` and all it finds is a string in the default field.  So the operation fails.

Since you want string there, you have to supply the Shell with a default verb to execute.  Under the `intfile` create shell\open\command. Enter the full path to your application, for example, "%ProgramFiles%\Notepad++\Notepad++.exe" "%1".

FileName is the Full path to the file you want to make a copy, so you need "%windir% and not WINDOWS.

**Edit**
I can't believe I'm condoning this method. . .

But I don't know of any way to add this without writing a program. . .

[image: Hacktastic]

**edit2:**

Ok here we go.

Key `.int` has `Default(SZ)` = `intfile` and Context Type(SZ) = `plain.text`. Under Key `.int`, you'll have subkey `Shellnew`.  The default should be empty.  Make a new empty string (Reg_SZ) and for the value put in the filename: `C:\windows\ShellNew\NewLocalization File'.

Under `intfile` make the default `New Localization File.`

Note the lack of double quotes. Now `intfile` needs the following subkeys: `shell`, make it's Default = `open`.  Next, make subkey `open` under *shell*.

Now make subkey `command` under *open*.

Put the full path of the program under the string with quotes. ie `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"`. Note there **are** double quotes.

**Edit:3**

So it looks like the OP ran into an unknown issue and solved it this way.

> Hrm ok figured it out! You were right mostly, and I was right a little. The problem was I had opened the file once and set the default program to notepad++ in the pop up dialogue. This created a key called **int_auto_file**. I went through the registry, very time consuming, and deleted all references to the .int extension. After that I rebuilt them and now it works perfectly.

Comment: I made the changes and yet it still isn't showing up in the right click menu.  It could be because the Default Regedit makes is a REG_SZ and to do the %ProgramFiles% needs a REG_EXPAND_SZ type, but I don't know how to edit the type and it won't let me delete the (Default), or even rename it.  Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: You can use Reg_SZ. You'll need to just put it in quotes. Just like I typed it.

Comment: Humm, you are right.  You can't change that to an expandable string type. Gotta hack it and put it in as a string.

Comment: I tried it both ways in open and neither worked.  I'm pretty confused now lol

Comment: So you get nothing in your menu?

Comment: Yeah, I can't see the New Localization File option in my menu. I am not sure if I am just missing something simple.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: I edited the question to show exactly what I have entered into the Registry as well.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is an int definition somewhere that is messing this up.  Because I entered everything exactly like you said and restarted the computer and still nothing.  I'm searching through the registry now.

Comment: I can't edit my last comment... anyway.  The reason I think this is that in Explorer windows it is calling .int files under the type column INT File, so I am not sure why it is doing that, I can't find that string anywhere in the registry

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not.  It would be calliing INT if `.ini` default program handler was was `INT`. Since you specify `intfile` for the Default, it would not do that. . .

Comment: For some reason under Type in explorer though it is given the name INT File, even though I have specified that it should be called a Localization File in my intfile key.

Comment: Hrm ok figured it out!  You were right mostly, and  I was right a little.  The problem was I had opened the file once and set the default program to notepad++ in the pop up dialogue.  This created a key called int_auto_file.  I went through the registry, very time consuming, and deleted all references to the .int extension.  After that I rebuilt them and now it works perfectly.  I'll mark you right, thank you so much for the help!  If you want to edit about the auto_file into your answer for anyone in the future it would probably help them too.  thank you again

Comment: I'll just highlight the problem you ran into for future readers.

Comment: Awesome that should take care of most issues.