# Custom File Type in ShellNew

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I am using a scripting language. It doesn't matter what it is, so I'll call it "LOL".
For easier scripting, I wanted to add a new entry to ShellNew. I tried to add new entry to registry.

> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.lol\ShellNew]
>
> "FileName"="Template.lol"

But it doesnt show up in Shell>New.
Yes, I have created the template file in "C:\Windows\ShellNew\"

There is no installation or anything, just saving the file with .lol extension and putting them into a certain directory.

Comment: I figured it out, turns out, I needed to create the custom file extension - http://superuser.com/questions/308958/creating-custom-file-extension-with-windows-registry

Comment: You could submit your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a \ missing in your registry file:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lol\ShellNew]
                  ^
"FileName"="Template.lol"
```